# Number of digits $d$ in $d^k$

Tags: number-theory

The title says it all really. For example, how many occurences of $6$ are there in $6^k$? It starts $6, 36, 216, \dots$ so $1, 1, 1,\dots$ The question can now be generalized into any digit or group of digits.

Comment: So what you are asking is whether there is a general formula for each degit?

Comment: The sequence fo $d=6$ continues with, at least to me, no clear rule with which to describe it: `0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 7, 3, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 6, 5, 5, 9, 6, 7, 7, 7, 5, 13, 8, 4, 5, 5, 2, 7, 4, 6, 5, 5, 12, 11, 4, 10, 7, 5, 11, 14, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 8, 10, 6, 8, 9, 6, 6, 7, 12, 9, 12, 11`. Sure, it is increasing. But I doubt you will find a nice formula for it...

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the question targets decimal base. If it was targeting binary base, then the answer would be trivial. After that, the easiest to analyze would probably be trinary base, so I suggest you start off with that. In other words, try to find out how many times the digit $2$ occurs in the number $2_3^k$ (as a function of $k$).

Comment: How about even some sort of approximate formula or a growth condition. Can we find a power $d^i$ with very large $i$, where the occurence of $d$ is very small? It's true, it seems to grow. Like somewhere in the vicinity of $2000$ it looks like $...161, 133, 147, 136, 154, 151, 149, 150, 150, 128, 150, 154, 133, 153, 137...$.

Comment: Problem is about 8 digits and characteristics when it is raised to any +ve integer (as in d^k).  We of course know that any digit raised to the power of 5 definitely has the least significant digit as the digit itself - eg 32 has 2, 243 has 3.

Comment: I was working with to get a 6 we are multiplying either 1 or 6. So it should be fairly easy, except for carries.

Comment: "except for carries": well, exactly. This is a hard problem, I think.

Comment: The general formula for base $10$ is: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} 1 - \left\lceil\left(\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{d^k}{10^{n-1}}\right\rfloor - 10\left\lfloor\frac{d^k}{10^n}\right\rfloor - d}{\left\lfloor\frac{d^k}{10^{n-1}}\right\rfloor - 10\left\lfloor\frac{d^k}{10^n}\right\rfloor + d}\right)^2\right\rceil$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general formula for base $10$ and $d\in[1,10-1]$:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}1-\left\lceil\left(\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{d^k}{10^{n-1}}\right\rfloor-10\left\lfloor\frac{d^k}{10^n}\right\rfloor-d}{\left\lfloor\frac{d^k}{10^{n-1}}\right\rfloor-10\left\lfloor\frac{d^k}{10^n}\right\rfloor+d}\right)^2\right\rceil$$

---

Here is a general formula for base $B$ and $d\in[1,B-1]$:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}1-\left\lceil\left(\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{d^k}{B^{n-1}}\right\rfloor-B\left\lfloor\frac{d^k}{B^n}\right\rfloor-d}{\left\lfloor\frac{d^k}{B^{n-1}}\right\rfloor-B\left\lfloor\frac{d^k}{B^n}\right\rfloor+d}\right)^2\right\rceil$$